# Failed refresh of access tokens on some accounts

Tags: oauth2

We have a large amount of users connected to our registered app (using the [OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant type](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)).  Nearly all of them refresh regularly with no problems.

However, with 6 of those accounts, we repeatedly see this error when trying to refresh an access token.

```
{
  error_description: "authentication failure"
  error: "invalid_grant"
}
```

I see lots of documentation and information on other "invalid_grant" errors but no explanation for "authentication failure".

Does anyone know what would cause that?  Is there a setting in a customer's "Connected Apps" configuration that could prevent some accounts from refreshing?

Comment: are these users chatter only users, did you check what was different about their profile (esp their license), also please post what permissions you have on the connect app setting

Comment: @rao These users are not chatter only.  We're asking for most read access in our scope (no write).  How can I check the their profiles for differences?

Comment: checking profile has to be done manually, we do not have a compare tool as much I know at least. Can you post the permissions enabled in your connected App, also is your org sso enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if these users have

as per this doc :
 https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US

there are only 2 reasons why you would get an invalid_grant

**invalid_grant—invalid authorization code** 
I suspect this cannot be true since other users are able to authenticate, if not I would have asked you to check if you are appending security token when the user logs in ( assuming username password flow)

**invalid_grant—IP restricted or invalid login hours**
This looks the probable reason of the 2, check on the user record if there is any king of restriction.

**login restriction:** you can see this all way at the bottom on the user record

**IP restriction :** https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_networkaccess.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link.  You're correct that the invalid authorization code wouldn't apply in this instance (as this is for a token refresh which doesn't use an authorization code).  I'll investigate the IP and login hour restrictions.

Comment: @chadmaughan was there any IP / Login restriction, would be awesome if you could post your own answer if the above were not the reasons :) Thanks.