# invalid_grant error code when trying to get the access token

Tags: rest-api, rest-service

I am able to get the "code" in my redirect Url but unable to get access token.

I tried sending POST request using POSTMAN and also from java code but "invalid_grant" error i got.

**Response {"error_description":"invalid authorization code","error":"invalid_grant"}**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
        post.setParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        post.setParameter("client_id", "MASKED");
        post.setParameter("client_secret", "MASKED");
        post.setParameter("redirect_uri", "https://www.facebook.com/");
        post.setParameter("code", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

What I am missing in the above code ?

Comment: Never post your client secret on a public forum

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed refresh of access tokens on some accounts](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37285/failed-refresh-of-access-tokens-on-some-accounts)

Comment: Sure, I forgot to remove secret key.
@Eric I have gone through the  Failed refresh of access tokens on some accounts question before posting this but the solution mentioned did not help me.

Comment: One more thing I want to add : I am able to get access token using CURL command where grant_type=password

Comment: How are you getting your authorization code? suggest you post all the code for your process

Comment: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MASKED&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/
I am directly firing this in browser which redirect me to redirect_url with code 
https://www.facebook.com/?code=MASKED

Comment: Check my answer here and test it out as it works properly. Then refactor to get what you want testing to see where you break it if at all.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83913/rest-api-to-create-account-from-one-sf-instance-to-another-sf-instance/83940#83940

Comment: URL building logic is same as mentioned in your answer, only the difference is you are using VF page and APEX controller to execute all logic      which is not in my case. Would that be the reason for this issue?

Comment: @Eric : Your answer help me in finding the issue. I was sending code without decoding, post.setParameter("code", "URLDecoder.decode("xxxxxxx")) has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" your should send  your request to "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize" so your code should look like

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize");
        post.setParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        post.setParameter("client_id", "MASKED");
        post.setParameter("client_secret", "MASKED");
        post.setParameter("redirect_uri", "https://www.facebook.com/");
        post.setParameter("code", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```